# What does User? has no member 'profileimageView' mean?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am unable to understand what exactly the error is trying to tell me. I tried fixing it by using `self` and changing classes. Still will not help. Need a guide that could help understand what exactly I am missing or doing wrong.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase

extension LoginController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func handleRegister(){
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text
            else {
                print("This form is not valid")
                return
        }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (self, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let uid = self?.uid else{
                return
            }

            //sucessfully authenticated user 
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

            // On the following line
            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {
                storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                })
            }

            let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://bbooks-96cac.firebaseio.com/")
            let userReference = ref.child("user").child(uid)
            let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
            userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: {
                (err, ref) in
                if err != nil {
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
                //  print("Saved user successfully into firebase DB")
            })
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What class is this code in? Show the class declaration.

Comment: Show more codes please..

Comment: @rmaddy  have updated the codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are misusing the term `self` (I'm surprised there is no error here). You need a better variable name:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (self, error) in
```

I would change `self` to `user` here and throughout what follows:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
```

Second, `user` is then an Optional so you need to unwrap it:

```
if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(user!.profileImageView.image!) {
```

Comment: thanks got it fixed!! but bit confused about the Optional thing didn't get the reason is there any article that could help Thanks again You a pro bro

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. There's no point asking _why_ it's an Optional; it's an Optional because that's what `createUser` hands you. If you don't know what an Optional _is_, you need to learn Swift before trying to go any further.